# DocC (Apple documentation compiler) resize image

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, markdown, docc

I am displaying an image in the docs like this.

```
![](screenshot.png)
```

But the image is too big.

I would like to resize it. Any suggestion?

The image is located in the `Resources` directory of the documentation.

Comment: Maybe try renaming `screenshot.png` to `screenshot@1x.png` which might resize the image accordingly.

Comment: Why don't you resize the original Image?